# Is there a nicer way to apply a function to both elements of a pair in a list than a list comprehension?

Tags: haskell

I use this a fair bit:

```
a' = [ (f x, f y) | (x, y) <- a ]
```

Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the [`(***)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Arrow.html#v%3a-42--42--42-) operator from [`Control.Arrow`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Arrow.html)

```
> map (f *** f) a
```

or define your own helper function

```
> let both f (x, y) = (f x, f y)
> map (both f) a
```

Comment: or perhaps just a lambda: `map (\(x, y) -> (f x, f y)) a`

Answer (score 11):

**Alternative solution:**

```
import Data.Bifunctor

bimap f f pair
```

`Bifunctor.bimap` is basically the same as `Arrow.(***)`, but works for other bifunctors (like `Either a b`), too.

**Digression:**

The reason why there is nothing predefined for your case is that you can't write instances of `Functor`, `Applicative` etc for `(,)` having the same element type twice. With an own "vector-like" type you wouldn't have this problem:

```
data Pair a = Pair a a deriving Show

instance Functor Pair where
  fmap f (Pair x y) = Pair (f x) (f y)
```

Now you can write things like `map (fmap (+1)) [Pair 12 14, Pair 17 18]`. Or if you want to use different operations on your `Pair`, you can go one step further:

```
instance Applicative Pair where 
  pure x = Pair x x
  (Pair f g) <*> (Pair x y) = Pair (f x) (g y)
```

If you work a lot with same-element-type pairs, it could be useful to switch from `(,)` to such a type.

Answer (score 5):

If you use [`lens`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens), you can use `over both f`, or `both %~ f`. This has the advantage of being more composable -- for example, if you have a pair of lists, you can use something like `both.mapped +~ toUpper` (`:: ([Char],[Char]) -> ([Char],[Char])`).